# Python, want to print float in exact format +-00.00

Tags: python, printing, floating-point

I need to format a float to the format +-00.00, tried the basic string formatting but can't get the leading + or - sign or two leading 0s if the value is fractional, any pointers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `'%+06.2f'` to set the width and precision appropriately. The equivalent using new-style format strings is `'{:+06.2f}'.format(n)` (or `'{0:+06.2f}'` if your version of Python requires the positional component).

Comment: or newer f-string feature `{n:+06.2f}` [available since 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings). It embeds both the variable and the format in the placeholder. [More](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-guide-to-string-formatting-in-python-using-f-strings-39e5c39589c3).

Answer (score 15):

'%+06.2f' % 1.1123344

```
+ means always use sign
0 means zero fill to full width.
6 is the total field width including sign and decimal point
.2 means 2 decimals.
f is float
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this should do it

```
x = 50.4796
a = -50.1246

print " %+2.2f" % (x)
print " %+2.2f" % (a)
```

The following should print

```
+50.48
-50.12
```