# How to round number to constant decimal

Tags: python

I want to use "math.sqrt" and my output should have 4 decimal after point even for numbers like "4". is there any func or way?!
I used "round(num_sqrt, 4)" but it didn't work.

my input is like:
1
2
3
19
output must be:
1.0000
1.4142
1.7320
4.3588
and my output is:
1.0
1.4142
1.7320
4.3588

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python, want to print float in exact format +-00.00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087589/python-want-to-print-float-in-exact-format-00-00)

Comment: It sounds like your question is more about __displaying__ the number, not actually changing its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from decimal import Decimal
import math

# example with sqrt function
y = Decimal(math.sqrt(4))
z = round(y, 4)
print(z) # output 2.0000

# First we take a float and convert it to a decimal
x = Decimal(16.0/7)
print(x)

# Then we round it to 4 places
output = round(x,4)
print(output) # outpun 2.2857
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you really need unnecessary zeros:

```
def format_floats(reference, values):
    formatted_values = []
    for i in range(len(values)):
        length = len(str(reference)[str(reference).find("."):])-1
        new_float = str(round(values[i], length))
        new_float += "0"*(len(str(reference))-len(new_float))
        formatted_values.append(new_float)

    return formatted_values

if __name__ == '__main__':

    reference = 0.12345
    values = [1.04, 2.045, 2.0]

    print(format_floats(reference, values))
```

output: ['1.04000', '2.04500', '2.00000']

Comment: Seems like a lot of work when you could do `print('{:.4f}'.format(n)`.

Comment: I used this code for input reference value kind of situation.